# Restarting JMS in running Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jms

Is there any way to restart JMS in running JBOSS.

Comment: JMS is an API, not a process. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Check if you can do it over JMX. I'm running a customized version of jetty (that resembles from far away a full J2EE container) and we're able to restart the broker (activemq) with JMX.

Answer (score 1):

Use the web-console, admin-console or jmx-console depending on which version of jboss you are using. They are deployed in the default JBoss server config.

http://localhost:8080/admin-console

You may want to set the passwords though..

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SecureJBoss